# useState при клике передавать id с первого раза (асинхронно)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Можно ли сделать хук асинхронным? У меня есть пара fetch запросов. На одном из них нужно, чтобы при клике бралось id и передавалось в фильтр, я всё сделал, но id меняется только на второй клик.

```
    const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
    const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState([]);
    const [categorySub, setCategorySub] = useState([]);

//При клике взять id и передать в хук

        const handleClick = (event) =>{
            setCategoryId(event.currentTarget.id)
        }

//Тут обычный запрос ничего интересного
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[depth]=1&filter[type]=0',{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => setCategory(result.data),
            )
    }, [])
```

Тут запрос который я обрабатываю при клике, categotyId это тот самый id, который я передаю.

```
    let getDataCategory = async () => {
        await fetch(`http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[parent_id][in]=${categoryId}&filter[type]=0`,{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => setCategorySub(result.data),
            )
    }
```

Тут вёрстка handleClick отдаёт id, getDataCategory делает fetch запрос.

```
                    {category.map(item =>
                    <div onClick={getDataCategory} className="equipment__special__check" key={item.id}>

                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} id={item.id} />
                            <label htmlFor={item.id} className="product__wrap">
                                <div className="img">
                                    <img src={url + item.image} alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p className="title">{item.title}</p>
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению я не нашел ответ, но можно не использовать хук для передачи id, а сделать всё в одной функции по инпуту и передать id в переменную let. Примерно так:

```
    let getDataCategory = async (event) => {
        let id = event.currentTarget.id
        await fetch(`http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[parent_id][in]=${id}&filter[type]=0`,{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => setCategorySub(result.data),
            )
        // let arrayCategory = [];

    }
```

Возможно кто нибудь ещё найдёт ответ на решение.